# How to flash MSP430G2211 MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, flash, msp430, energia

After experimenting a light sensing tool on TI MSP430G2ET with MSP430G2553, I designed a real scheamatic and PCB with MSP430G2211.
I used MSP430G2211 because it has less pinout and smaller than MSP430G2553.

But I couldn't flash program into MSP430G2211.

The SBW pins and power pins are correctly wired from Lunchpad to MSP430G2211.

[image]

I tried `mspdebug` on shell prompt, but I got this error.

```
$ sudo mspdebug ezfet -d /dev/ttyACM0 "prog ./firmware.hex" 
MSPDebug version 0.25 - debugging tool for MSP430 MCUs
Copyright (C) 2009-2017 Daniel Beer <dlbeer@gmail.com>
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Chip info database from MSP430.dll v3.3.1.4 Copyright (C) 2013 TI, Inc.

Trying to open /dev/ttyACM0 at 460800 bps...
Reset communications...
Version: 2.12.0.0, HW: 0xaaadaaad
Reset firmware...
hal_proto_execute: HAL exception: 0xffff
hal_proto_execute: fid: 0x51
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your launchpad's EZ-FET is broken.
It is not stable, and by some reason, it becomes broken easily.
Try to reset the firmware of EZ-FET by running,

```
$ mspdebug tilib
```

, and then try your commands again.

I've experimented with several MSP programmers before.
The EZ-FET included in Launchpads were unstable for external usage.
There're some cheap stable programmers like MSPFET-430UIF.

Comment: The programmer of launchpad is EZ-FET, so the command should be `mspdeug ezfet`, isn't it?

Comment: `tilib` is not meaning a programmer variant. It is dedicated keyword for communicating with programmers and updating firmware of programmer itself. For example, to update the firmware of programmer, run `mspdebug tilib --allow-fw-update`.

Comment: It worked magically. Thank you. WOuld you explain a little more why the EZ-FET firmware has broken?